# how to change the intent when ball touch the bottom or top the canvas

Tags: android, android-animation

in my game ball moves from top to bottom and bottom to top,my requirement is when ball touches top edge or     bottom edge i want to print a toast message like "game over".later i want to move control some other intent.to animate the ball i am using following code

```
public class AnimatedView extends ImageView{


    static int count=0;
    private Context mContext;
    int x = 130;
    int y = 450;
    private float a,b;
    private int xVelocity = 25;
    private int yVelocity = 20;
    private Handler h;
    private final int FRAME_RATE = 30;
    BitmapDrawable ball;
    boolean touching;
    boolean dm_touched = false;
    float move=3;
    int bm_x = 0, bm_y = 0, bm_offsetx, bm_offsety,bm_w,bm_h;
    boolean paused;


    public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {  
        super(context, attrs);  
        mContext = context;  
        h = new Handler();
        } 

    @Override
    public void buildDrawingCache() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.buildDrawingCache();
    }
    private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Log.e("game","run called");
            if(touching = true)
            invalidate(); 
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  
        BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);  
        if (x<0 && y <0) {
            //x = this.getWidth()/2;
            y = c.getHeight()/2;


        } else {
            y += yVelocity;

            if (y >( this.getHeight() - ball.getBitmap().getHeight()) ||y <0) {
                yVelocity = yVelocity*-1;
            }
        }
        c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  
       //Log.e("sarat",""+touching);
      if(touching){
         // Log.e("game","iftouch called called");
        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);    
        bm_w=ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
        bm_h=ball.getBitmap().getHeight();
      }

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Log.d("game","ontouch called");
        int touchType = event.getAction();

         switch(touchType){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                a = event.getX();
                b = event.getY();
                touching = true;
                if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) 
                  {
                    if(bm_h+a>600 ||bm_h+b<0){ 
                      Toast.makeText(getContext(),"game over",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                break;

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                 //x and y give you your touch coordinates
                  a = event.getX();
                  b = event.getY();
                  touching = true;

                  Log.e("s",""+ a);
                  Log.e("s",""+ b);
                  Log.e("s",""+ x);
                  Log.e("s",""+ y);
                  Log.e("s",""+ bm_w);
                  Log.e("s",""+ bm_h);
                  if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) { 
                      count++;
                    MainActivity.setCount(count);

                      Log.i("score",""+count);

                    }
                  if (dm_touched) {
                      if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) { 
                      move+=2;

                      y = yVelocity*-1;

                    }}

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                 a = event.getX();
                  b = event.getY();
                 if(a>x+20&&a<330&&b<=y+320&&b>y){
                 invalidate();}
                 if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) { 
                    Log.e("game","clicked");
                }

                default:

                    dm_touched = true;

                }

                return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyDrawingCache() {

        count=0;
        super.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's nice.  Did you have a question as well?

Comment: did u understand my question

Comment: No, since the only "question" is in the title which asks about `Intent`.  You are not using intents in any of the code you have shown and there is no other question in the post.

Comment: sorry for that,actually my intention is when image touches bottom or top of the screen "game is over" like that i am thinking for that i need to develop one more activity to display game is over something...    so i need to write some condition for game over

Comment: So this test is not working? `if(bm_h+a>600 ||bm_h+b<0){ 
                      Toast.makeText(getContext(),"game over",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: sorry for late reply,yes it is not working